# Net Core REST API - Returning JSON with and without a model

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

On a HttpGet operation...

The database is returning a fully formed JSON string that needs no translation before returning back to the user.

Currently, I am deserializing this JSON into a C# model/class and then returning that model.

What are the trade-offs for just returning the JSON string returned from the DB (no longer using the C# Model)?

I asked because this seems like it might be an anti-pattern with respect to the benefits a model provides.

Note that I understand time is saved by not having to deserialize the JSON from the DB into the model and then serializing the model back to a JSON string to respond to the client.  However,

Example with Model:

```
        var response = await GetDataByParams(functionName, npgSqlParams);

        List<EmployeeInfo> model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EmployeeInfo>>(response);

        return model;
```

Vs:

```
        var response = await GetDataByParams(functionName, npgSqlParams);

        return response;
```

**Note**: We are using postgres and Npgsql. Not using Entity Framework.

**Note**: We are using Swagger so I know we will lose the model definition in the API documentation.

QUESTION: How does this affect mock testing the API?

QUESTION: What if the JSON changes and breaks the contract with the client?
My thought is that using Models guarantees the contract.  If the JSON returned from the database violates the model then an exception would happen on the server. Not using a model would push the exception back to the client.

Answer (score 0):

As a general practice, it is indicated not to return Domain models/Domain response directly to client. Using DTOs for that (like `EmployeeInfo`) is the correct approach.

By using DTOs you have more control over the output data, including serialization options, hiding properties which you don't want to expose to the client.

Also, if your Domain changes, your DTOs will stay the same, and the client will not be affected.

Comment: In this scenario, there is no manipulation of the data needed. No hiding data.

Comment: Just to clarify, the question is actually, what is the trade-off for not using Models/DTOs and instead just returning straight JSON that was provided by the postgres function.

Comment: If you do not use DTOs, the service consumers (clients) are more vulnerable to Domain changes. I don't think skipping the deserialization process would save significant time/resources.

Answer (score 0):

Returning the string directly from the database avoids the overhead of

- Deserializing to DTO and
- Reserializing to JSON after the controller returns the DTO, but
- Tests will be a bit more brittle because they would rely on string matching, etc. and the intent of the test's assertions won't be as easily expressed as with an assert on properties of a DTo.

Serializing the database to a DTO first

- Adds that overhead, but
- Allows you to make any manipulations or other type-safe interactions with the DTO you might need first, and
- Allows for easy testing

There's also a hybrid approach of tokenizing the JSON using [JObject.Parse](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Parse.htm)() (if Newtonsoft) or [JsobDocument.Parse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument.parse?view=net-5.0) (if `System.Text.Json`) that

- Tokenizes the result, allowing you to
- Manipulate the structure without having a DTO, and
- May be reasonably tested by accessing the parsed structure

You'd have to measure it, but the first method is likely to give you the highest performance, but least flexibility (the latter, which seems like a tradeoff you're willing to accept for your case).

The second method is probably the most common case "in the wild", and for most situations makes the most sense. The point you raise about how the safety a DTO presents by immediately surfacing "broken" contracts is a good one. Knowing about those kinds of errors early reduces the maintenance costs of your APIs and reduces the chance the client gets an incorrect result.

Comment: Thanks.  I understand there may be some performance benefit to not deserializing/serializing.  These are small objects.  As I think through this further I am wondering how it affects mock testing the API.  It is easy to mock test using POCO classes.  if I have to create JSON test strings to mock test the API we run the risk of the test json string not matching the function's son response if someone changes it...

Comment: Testability is definitely an aspect. I'll add that in...

Comment: Thanks.  I appreciate you taking the time to think through the issue with me.